# Can I use the same words in my manuscript in writing my accessible summaries?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, self-plagiarism

I am drafting an accessible summary for my article almost ready to be published in a top-tier peer-review journal. I wonder if I can directly use what is in my article without the concern of self-plagiarism? Technically the summary is a part of the article and they will be published at the same time but I searched online, no specific requirement or restriction were offered.

FYI: What Are Accessible Summaries? Written in nontechnical language, accessible summaries provide information about each manuscript’s goals, its design and approach, and its results, highlighting findings that may be of interest to those outside academia, such as language educators

Answer (score 1):

There should be little doubt that you aren't plagiarizing yourself. The ideas are yours and you are expressing them as such. Moreover, there is a clear link between the abstract and the original. This is equivalent to a citation. It is that "citation" that avoids the issue.

Note that plagiarism isn't fundamentally about "words" but about ideas.